# Assigning Different Onclicks Depending On Which Submit Button Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have an `asp.net` form which has 3 button's which trigger the relevent modal for for the button clicked and for the user to enter details in.  Currently each modal has an `OnClick` which take to my code behind.

I am trying to now implemet a success modal to be displayed when the 'Submit' on each of these modals is clicked.

I want to only hav eone success modal shared by all three of my other one's.  I have sort of working as the intital modal closes and my success modal is then displayed BUT it doesn't write to my DB.

If i ad one of my `OnClick` to my button on my success modal, it post's to my DB so i'm thinking i need to some how, add an `OnClick` to my 'Close' button on success modal but i need it to populate with the correct `OnClick` depending on which button was first selected.

**Current Code**

*Data entry modal submit buttons*

```
<asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-success" ID="btnSubmitNewFunc" runat="server" Text="Submit" ToolTip="Click to submit your request." data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalSuccess" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-dismiss="modal" OnClick="btnSubmitNewFunc_Click" />
<asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-success" ID="btnSubmitBug" runat="server" Text="Submit" ToolTip="Click to submit your request." data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalSuccess" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-dismiss="modal" OnClick="btnSubmitBug_Click" />
<asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-success" ID="btnSubmitNewPlace" runat="server" Text="Submit" ToolTip="Click to submit your request." data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalSuccess" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-dismiss="modal" OnClick="btnSubmitNewPlace_Click" />
```

*Success modal close button*

```
<asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-warning" ID="btnModalSuccess" runat="server" Text="Close" ToolTip="Click to close this screen." />
```

Comment: I think I understand what you want to achieve but you have to share the relevant JS code. Also what do you mean by "I have sort of working as the intital modal closes and my success modal is then displayed BUT it doesn't write to my DB." What does not write to DB?

Comment: @marekful Currently (without the 'Success' modal) when the user fills in the fields on one of the 3 modals, when they hit 'Submit' it puts all details entered into a DB table as the current `OnClick` for each button do different things in my code behind so i need a way of adding the correct `Onclick` depending on which initial button was clicked so it uses the correct code behind

Comment: @marekful I dont currently have any JS to share as this is the bit im unsure on how to write and get working with by success 'Close' button

Comment: It's quite easy to dynamically assign, remove or reassign different handlers to certain events, like in your case to the click event of the final modal. However, without seeing any code I cannot advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to submit the data when clicking on `btnModalSuccess`, you can first save the original command name in a hidden field:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenCommand" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmitNewFunc" ... OnClientClick="return showSuccess('NewFunc');" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmitBug" ... OnClientClick="return showSuccess('Bug');" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmitNewPlace" ... OnClientClick="return showSuccess('NewPlace');" />
```

with the help of this Javascript utility function:

```
function showSuccess(cmd) {
    $('#hiddenCommand').val(cmd); 
    $('#modalsuccess').modal('show');
    return false; // To prevent the postback
}
```

In the event handler of `btnModalSuccess`, the processing would depend on the command stored in the hidden field:

```
protected void btnModalSuccess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (hiddenCommand.Value)
    {
        case "NewFunc":
            ProcessNewFunc();
            break;

        case "Bug":
            ProcessBug();
            break;

        case "NewPlace":
            ProcessNewPlace();
            break;
    }
}
```

---

That being said, I may suggest that you post the data to the server first, and then display the Success modal. Otherwise, the user could see the success modal and close the browser without clicking on `btnModalSuccess`, thus preventing the data from being saved to the database.

It could look like this in code-behind:

```
protected void btnSubmitNewFunc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Save data to DB here
    ...
    ShowSuccessModal();
}

protected void btnSubmitBug_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Save data to DB here
    ...
    ShowSuccessModal();
}

protected void btnSubmitNewPlace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Save data to DB here
    ...
    ShowSuccessModal();
}

private void ShowSuccessModal()
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ShowSuccess", "$('#modalsuccess').modal('show');", true);
}
```

The button `btnModalSuccess` would simply dismiss the modal without causing a postback:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnModalSuccess" runat="server" Text="Close" ... OnClientClick="$('#modalsuccess').modal('hide'); return false;" />
```